# The content of element type "tiles-definitions" must match "(definition)+"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles, apache-tiles

I am using `Apache tiles` in my `Spring MVC` project. 
The whole thing is working fine, until i add another `defination` in my `<tiles-definations>` tag.

When i add multiple `<defination>` in my `<tiles-defination>` tag, it starts giving me following error message.

> The content of element type "tiles-definitions" must match
>   "(definition)+".

**Tiles.xml**

```
<definition name="common" template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/templates/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="sidebar" value="/WEB-INF/templates/sidebar.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/templates/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="tilesHomePage" extends="common">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/home.jsp"  />
</definition>


<defination name="studentForm" extends="common">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/form.jsp"/>
</defination>
```

I have google this, but unable to find any solution. Kindly guide me.

Comment: `defination` should be `definition`... The `a` must be an `i`.

Comment: I have been trying this for 2 days!! can't believe it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spelling Mistake- It Should be `<definition>`, rather than `<defination>`